# Is there a way to get the mean of only certain values in a data frame rather than whole rows or columns?

Tags: r

[image: Image of data frame example]
I need to get the mean of specific values such as at coordniate points [1,1] [1,5] [1,9] so it would be absorbance_one_norm value at row 1 5 and 9

Would it make more sense to create a new data frame? Not sure how to grab specific values by doing that or just using a mean function. Any help is appreciated

An example of the output I want would be a new data frame with mean values

```
absorbance_1_mean,  absorbance_2_mean
.33333              .3333
.33333               .33333
.3333                .3333
```

Edit: I am new to r so please be kind

Comment: Please provide an example of coordinate inputs that is consistent with the data provided (the data shown does not have 9 columns and it is not clear whether you expect a value for each of the two groups of coordinates or just one overall value) and show the expected result.  Please read the information at the top of the [tag:r] tag which provides information on how to ask a question.  Note the part about using dput.

Comment: I tried to add more examples, I hope this helps a bit. Still learning

Comment: From your example, you have the rows and columns reversed. The coordinate [1, 9] refers to row 1, column 9. It seems like you are looking for absorbance_one at row 9, so you would want `df[9, 1]` (where `df` is the name of your dataframe).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use row/column index to extract the elements and get the `mean`

```
mean(df1[cbind(c(1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2), c(1, 5, 9, 1, 5, 9))])
```

Comment: I will it is just not working for me  getting Error in as.matrix(x)[i] : subscript out of bounds

Comment: @MorganWood that error occurs only if you don't have either those rows or columns.  It is based on your description in the post so I assumed you have those many rows/columns

Answer (score 1):

If you want the mean for the same rows across columns, the following (using base R) will work by subsetting the rows and then taking the means of each row.

```
library(tibble)
# Make example data
df <- tibble(!!!lapply(1:10, function(x) runif(100)), 
             .name_repair = ~paste0("absorbance", 1:10))
# Make vector containing desired rows
desired_rows <- c(1, 5, 9)
# Take the mean down each column 
apply(df[desired_rows, ], 2, mean)
```